# grails create-app not working in Grails 3.1.3

Tags: grails, grails-3.1

I cannot create a working app in grails 3.1.3 in Windows 7.

```
grails create-app temp
cd temp
grails --stacktrace --verbose
```

Results:

```
| Error Error occurred running Grails CLI: Profile [org.grails.profiles:base:3.1.3] declares and invalid dependency on parent profile [org.grails.profiles:base:3.1.3]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Profile [org.grails.profiles:base:3.1.3] declares and invalid dependency on parent profile [org.grails.profiles:base:3.1.3]
    at org.grails.cli.profile.AbstractProfile$_getExtends_closure4.doCall(AbstractProfile.groovy:331)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:294)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1021)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:426)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:442)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.collect(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:3170)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.collect(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:3140)
    at org.grails.cli.profile.AbstractProfile.getExtends(AbstractProfile.groovy:328)
    at org.grails.cli.profile.AbstractProfile.getCommands(AbstractProfile.groovy:411)
    at org.grails.cli.profile.repository.AbstractJarProfileRepository$JarProfile.getCommands(AbstractJarProfileRepository.groovy:107)
    at org.grails.cli.profile.AbstractProfile.getCompleters(AbstractProfile.groovy:339)
    at org.grails.cli.GrailsCli.setupCompleters(GrailsCli.groovy:406)
    at org.grails.cli.GrailsCli.handleInteractiveMode(GrailsCli.groovy:388)
    at org.grails.cli.GrailsCli.execute(GrailsCli.groovy:275)
    at org.grails.cli.GrailsCli.main(GrailsCli.groovy:162)
| Error Error occurred running Grails CLI: Profile [org.grails.profiles:base:3.1.3] declares and invalid dependency on parent profile [org.grails.profiles:base:3.1.3]
```

I have cleared my repo cashes by deleting the .gradle, .grails, & .m2 directories on my C:\Users\my_user folder. And I have checked my JAVA_HOME and GRAILS_HOME env vars are correct. If I enter grails --version at the command prompt I get:

```
| Grails Version: 3.1.3
| Groovy Version: 2.4.6
| JVM Version: 1.8.0_73
```

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not your fault; it's a known [issue](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/9759), which [has been patched](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/commit/4b61ce3a0e9d7b886713cc40efee27bdec7108a5)  and [added as a milestone to Grails 3.1.4](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/milestones/grails-3.1.4).

As a workaround downgrade Grails. It'll work in 3.1.2 or 3.1.1 versions.

---

**Update**: of course right now it's recommended to *upgrade*, instead of *downgrade*.